# Not able to upload file in content type form without filling all required fields

Tags: files

Uploading a file in node/add/mycontenttype is failing and displaying required field validation errors for fields that have not been filled out.

If I fill all required field then upload the file it works.
My drupal version is 7.28
Could any one who knows please help me sort out this issue?

Comment: What is the version of Drupal core you are running?

Comment: Due to your Drupal version the first thing you should do is check out https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005

Comment: Do you have any modules installed that modify the node forms? For example the save draft module or anything that modifies file fields or validation? Or any custom modules?

Comment: Thanks for giving useful instruction,i am using clientside validation module when i configure it for my content type and Override default options for Validate options here i checked Validate fields on submit then it is working fine.This issue due to clientside validation.